# Ruby syntax used in Rails Book unknown

Tags: ruby, syntax

Really short question:

```
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)
```

What is the syntactic meaning of **"product: product"**? I never encountered this before as a Ruby language construct. For the author of "Agile Web Development with Rails" Edition 4 it seems to work out of the box. But for me it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is hash syntax using in ruby 1.9. Try to use ruby 1.9.2 or 1.9.3.

Comment: Note that it is hash syntax *only when using symbols as keys*. This will not work: `h = {"a":"b"}`.

Comment: @Mark: Only when using *some* symbols as keys, this will not work either: `h = { $set: { a: 'b' } }`.

Comment: @muistooshort Who uses `:$set` as a symbol? :)

Comment: They show up all the time when using [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24all) so I use them almost every day. Also, anything (even another Hash) can be a hash key and the JSON style notation won't work with anything that isn't a symbol (and only a limited set of symbols at that).

Answer (score 2):

It's new syntax in ruby 1.9

It's equivalent to using a hash rocket in 1.8

e.g./

```
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:product => product)
```

Comment: No, the rocket isn't going away, try doing this without it: `h = { [] => 1, :'a.b' => 2, 3 => 4, :$set => { 'a' => 'b' } }`. That blog post is overly dramatic nonsense.